# Return all related rows from join table if just a single matches

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Lets say I have a table called `events`

```
event_id | event_name | event_time
---------|------------|-----------
1        | Holiday    | 09:00
2        | Meeting    | 10:00
```

Then I have a table called `attendees`

```
attendee_id | event_id | person_id
------------|----------|----------
1           | 1        | 19
2           | 1        | 28
3           | 1        | 89
4           | 1        | 100
5           | 2        | 7
6           | 2        | 19
7           | 2        | 22
8           | 2        | 28
```

Weirdly, I need to return the event and all of its attendees, if I have a match on just a single person. If there is no match, I don't want the event returned at all.

```
SELECT events.*, GROUP_CONCAT(attendee_id, event_id, person_id SEPARATOR ',') AS attendees
FROM events
LEFT JOIN attendees ON events.event_id = attendees.event_id
WHERE attendees.person_id IN (89)
GROUP BY event_id
```

This currently returns the event with just the single attendee in the 'attendees' column.

I know it seems counter intuitive, but is there a way I can actually return the event and all of the attendees included on the event without doing further filtering downstream?

**Expected Result**

```
event_id | event_name | event_time | attendees
-------- | ---------- | ---------- | ---------
1        | Holiday    | 09:00      | 19,28,89,100
```

Comment: Could you provide your expected result? I am not quite sure if I understand your requirement...

Comment: Why isn't "Meeting" also a valid return?

Comment: Sorry Rick, Yes meeting should have been returned if I specified the attendee ID of 19, I've changed SQL to look for attendee ID 89, so just the single event is returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need to change the `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE attendees.event_id IN (SELECT event_id FROM attendees WHERE person_id = 19)
```

So use this:

```
SELECT 
  e.event_id, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(a.person_id SEPARATOR ',') AS attendees
FROM events e LEFT JOIN attendees a
ON e.event_id = a.event_id
WHERE a.event_id IN (SELECT event_id FROM attendees WHERE person_id = 19)
GROUP BY e.event_id
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2djog5GTLZ33VDKZE7t9B5/1).
Results:

```
| event_id | attendees    |
| -------- | ------------ |
| 1        | 28,89,100,19 |
| 2        | 7,19,22,28   |
```

Comment: An easier and better for performance way to do this is simply to remove the *LEFT* from the join clause.

Comment: The problem is not the type of the join.

Comment: Thank-you, It sounds like a subquery might be the only way to achieve this within SQL.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want events that have attendees, the do not use the **LEFT JOIN** in your **ON** clause.

Also, remove the where clause unless you only want a specific person/attendee in your results.

Note that in the example, although you did not show the person table, I've added it and referenced one column from that table. Adjust if you like to use the actual column name.

```
SELECT 
    a.*, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(
        a.attendee_id, 
        b.event_id, 
        b.person_id ,
        c.person_name
        SEPARATOR ',') AS attendees
FROM events a
JOIN attendees b
    ON a.event_id = b.event_id
JOIN persons c
    ON b.person_id = c.person_id
WHERE b.person_id IN (19)   /* Remove unless you are looking for a specific person/attendee */
GROUP BY event_id
```